# Minimum value of $\sqrt[3]{x}yz$ is

Tags: inequality

> If $x+y+z=14.$ Then minimum value of $\sqrt[3]{x}yz$, where $x,y,z>0$

Try: let $x=t^3.$ Then $y+z=14-t^3$

So we have $$tyz\leq\frac{1}{4}t\bigg(y+z\bigg)^2=\frac{t}{4}(14-t^3)^2$$
Could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Comment: Do you know any calculus?

Comment: You can choose $z$ as small as you like, so there is no minimum, but the infimum is zero.

Comment: @DXT, You need minimum or maximum as anyone/two of $x,y,z$ can be set arbitrarily so that the product is arbitrarily small$(>0)$

Comment: Is this $$\sqrt[3]{x}yz$$ or $$\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using AM GM inequality,

$$\dfrac{x+3\cdot\dfrac y3+3\cdot\dfrac z3}{1+3+3}\ge\sqrt[1+3+3]{x\left(\dfrac y3\right)^3\left(\dfrac z3\right)^3}$$

$$\implies2^7\ge\dfrac{xy^3z^3}{3^6}$$

Take cube root both side

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this gives an upper bound for the product, but the question was for the minimum.

Comment: @MartinR, I firmly believe the minimum is not expected as the product can be made arbitrarily by setting  anyone/two of $x,y,z$ to be arbitrarily small